# repeater paging viewstate

Tags: c#, repeater

So finally.. I have my repeater working as I want it to be full of buttons, radio button, image buttons, update panels, AJAX modal popups and a heavy code behind each event.

found out that my repeater getting very slow when the items exceeds 20, so I used paging as a solution.  the problem is when I do changes and move on to the next page, all changes are gone when getting back to the previous page. (checked radios, labels, etc all back to normal state).

please help, my system is in production now.

---

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            loadTasks();
        }
```

---

```
     void loadTasks()
    {

        string evalidxxx = Request.QueryString["eval_id"].Trim().Replace(" ", "");


        SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GappConnectionString2"].ConnectionString);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Prog_Task_link.pt_seq, Tasks.task_name, Tasks.task_id FROM Tasks INNER JOIN Prog_Task_link ON Tasks.task_id = Prog_Task_link.task_id INNER JOIN Programs ON Prog_Task_link.prog_id = programs.prog_id INNER JOIN Data_Tracker_prepare ON Programs.prog_id = Data_Tracker_prepare.dtpre_prog_id WHERE Data_Tracker_prepare.eval_id =" + evalidxxx, conn);
            System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

            sqlAdapter.Fill(dt);




            PagedDataSource objPds = new PagedDataSource();
            objPds.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
            objPds.AllowPaging = true;
            objPds.PageSize = 10;

            objPds.CurrentPageIndex = CurrentPage;

            lblCurrentPage.Text = "Page: " + (CurrentPage + 1).ToString() + " of "
                + objPds.PageCount.ToString();

            //Disable Prev or Next buttons if necessary
            LinkPrevPage.Enabled = !objPds.IsFirstPage;
            LinkNextPage.Enabled = !objPds.IsLastPage;

            rptr1.DataSource = objPds;
            rptr1.DataBind();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
        finally { conn.Close(); }

    }



    public int CurrentPage
    {
        get
        {
            // look for current page in ViewState
            object o = this.ViewState["_CurrentPage"];
            if (o == null)
                return 0;      // default to showing the first page
            else
                return (int)o;
        }

        set
        {
            this.ViewState["_CurrentPage"] = value;
        }
    }

    protected void LinkPrevPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentPage -= 1;
        loadTasks();

    }

    protected void LinkNextPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentPage += 1;
        loadTasks();

    }
```

Comment: You're going to need to include some code samples if you expect anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: added the paging code. as I said, paging is working ok.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using .net 4.0 you can use EnablePersistedSelection="True"

sorry to say but this can not be done.. 
When you are in page one, the rest pages are not actual exists in repeater.

after paging to next page next data will be load so previous data will be reset

i mean to say, When you ask to select all radios, buttons,check boxes are mean what you see. After you change page the other controls are set to default (probably unchecked or reset)

So re design your user interface for what you want to do. And as my suggestion take another button to save the current state of the page.. and then go to next page..

anything other that i can help ??

Comment: saving each page will not be useful, the user should be able to return to the previous page and see/edit the changes. is there any other way?

Comment: I will try to convert my repeater to list view and give it the same name, hope there is not much to change in the code though.

Comment: yess.. it will not take much efforts to do so.. plz mark as answer if u found it useful.. :)

Comment: it didn't work. I think the only solution would be storing the values during paging. ahhhhhhh, lots of coding...